What should i do after "sudo systemctl stop gdm" command?
I was trying to stop and restart my display manager in my VM. but after "sudo systemctl stop gdm". I can't seem to access any virtual terminal. my ubuntu is running on VT2 and I was using these commands on VT3 but for some reason after the commands execution all my VTs shut down and I cant access any of them further.

Just reboot the system using Ctrl-Alt-Del? What do you actually want to do?

i was trying to restart it using other virtual terminals beside the one on which my ubuntu  is running on
